# How to group time by every n minutes in R

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, aggregate

I have a dataframe with a lot of time series:

```
1   0:03    B   1
2   0:05    A   1
3   0:05    A   1
4   0:05    B   1
5   0:10    A   1
6   0:10    B   1
7   0:14    B   1
8   0:18    A   1
9   0:20    A   1
10  0:23    B   1
11  0:30    A   1
```

I want to group the time series into every 6 minutes and count the frequency of A and B:

```
1   0:06    A   2
2   0:06    B   2
3   0:12    A   1
4   0:12    B   1
5   0:18    A   1
6   0:24    A   1
7   0:24    B   1
8   0:18    A   1
9   0:30    A   1
```

Also, the class of the time series is character. What should I do?

Comment: Double check your output data frame, the times are out of order and it just seems off. Also, do you want the intervals [0, 6), [6, 12), [12, 18), etc. or (0, 6], (6, 12], (12, 18], etc. ?

Answer (score 7):

### Here's an approach to convert times to `POSIXct`, `cut` the times by 6 minute intervals, then `count`.

First, you need to specify the year, month, day, hour, minute, and seconds of your data. This will help with scaling it to larger datasets.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# sample data
d <- data.frame(t = paste0("2019-06-02 ", 
                           c("0:03","0:06","0:09","0:12","0:15",
                             "0:18","0:21","0:24","0:27","0:30"), 
                           ":00"),
                g = c("A","A","B","B","B"))

d$t <- ymd_hms(d$t) # convert to POSIXct with `lubridate::ymd_hms()`
```

If you check the `class` of your new date column, you will see it is "POSIXct".

```
> class(d$t)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Now that the data is in "POSIXct", you can `cut` it by minute intervals! We will add this new grouping factor as a new column called `tc`.

```
d$tc <- cut(d$t, breaks = "6 min")  
d
                     t g                  tc
1  2019-06-02 00:03:00 A 2019-06-02 00:03:00
2  2019-06-02 00:06:00 A 2019-06-02 00:03:00
3  2019-06-02 00:09:00 B 2019-06-02 00:09:00
4  2019-06-02 00:12:00 B 2019-06-02 00:09:00
5  2019-06-02 00:15:00 B 2019-06-02 00:15:00
6  2019-06-02 00:18:00 A 2019-06-02 00:15:00
7  2019-06-02 00:21:00 A 2019-06-02 00:21:00
8  2019-06-02 00:24:00 B 2019-06-02 00:21:00
9  2019-06-02 00:27:00 B 2019-06-02 00:27:00
10 2019-06-02 00:30:00 B 2019-06-02 00:27:00
```

Now you can `group_by` this new interval (`tc`) and your grouping column (`g`), and count the frequency of occurences. Getting the frequency of observations in a group is a fairly common operation, so `dplyr` provides `count` for this:

```
count(d, g, tc)
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  g     tc                      n
  <fct> <fct>               <int>
1 A     2019-06-02 00:03:00     2
2 A     2019-06-02 00:15:00     1
3 A     2019-06-02 00:21:00     1
4 B     2019-06-02 00:09:00     2
5 B     2019-06-02 00:15:00     1
6 B     2019-06-02 00:21:00     1
7 B     2019-06-02 00:27:00     2
```

If you run `?dplyr::count()` in the console, you'll see that `count(d, tc)` is simply a wrapper for `group_by(d, g, tc) %>% summarise(n = n())`.

Comment: It would be ideal to have POSIXct values, but one can get around it (change HH:MM to just MM). Also, the output df in your answer doesn't look like OPs ideal df (which has some issues, at the time of writing); it's missing A and B counts. Was that intentional?

Comment: Missing A and B counts is my bad (see edited answer)! Thanks for pointing that out. WRT HH:MM, `cut` only works with POSIXct, and the OP suggests that the actual data is large, so converting POSIXct seems wise, especially if the data starts to span days.

Comment: No prob, that's what this is all about. I agree, POSIXct is the way to go.

Comment: Please, use the data provided by the OP instead of making up you own data from scratch. This will help the OP to apply your solution to his dataset as well as to verify that your solution is returning the expected result. -Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the sample dataset, the time series is given as time-of-day, i.e., without date.

The `data.table` package has the `ITime` class which is a time-of-day class stored as the integer number of seconds in the day. With `data.table`, we can use a *rolling join* to map times to the upper limit of the 6 minutes intervals (*right-closed intervals*):

```
library(data.table)

# coerce from character to class ITime
setDT(ts)[, time := as.ITime(time)]

# create sequence of breaks
breaks <- as.ITime(seq(as.ITime("0:00"), as.ITime("23:59:59"), as.ITime("0:06")))

# rolling join and aggregate
ts[, CJ(breaks, group, unique = TRUE)
   ][ts, on = .(group, breaks = time), roll = -Inf, .(x.breaks, group)
     ][, .N, by = .(upper = x.breaks, group)]
```

which returns

> ```
>       upper group N
> 1: 00:06:00     B 2
> 2: 00:06:00     A 2
> 3: 00:12:00     A 1
> 4: 00:12:00     B 1
> 5: 00:18:00     B 1
> 6: 00:18:00     A 1
> 7: 00:24:00     A 1
> 8: 00:24:00     B 1
> 9: 00:30:00     A 1
> ```

#### Addendum

If the direction of the rolling join is changed (`roll = +Inf` instead of `roll = -Inf`) we get *left-closed intervals*

```
ts[, CJ(breaks, group, unique = TRUE)
   ][ts, on = .(group, breaks = time), roll = +Inf, .(x.breaks, group)
     ][, .N, by = .(lower = x.breaks, group)]
```

which changes the result significantly:

> ```
>       lower group N
> 1: 00:00:00     B 2
> 2: 00:00:00     A 2
> 3: 00:06:00     A 1
> 4: 00:06:00     B 1
> 5: 00:12:00     B 1
> 6: 00:18:00     A 2
> 7: 00:18:00     B 1
> 8: 00:30:00     A 1
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
ts <- fread("
1   0:03    B   1
2   0:05    A   1
3   0:05    A   1
4   0:05    B   1
5   0:10    A   1
6   0:10    B   1
7   0:14    B   1
8   0:18    A   1
9   0:20    A   1
10  0:23    B   1
11  0:30    A   1"
, header = FALSE
, col.names = c("rn", "time", "group", "value"))
```

Comment: Saw your gh issue, not sure I follow the request, but this also seems to work: `clab = structure(seq(0L, 86400L-360L, by=360L), class="ITime"); DT[, .N, keyby=.(cut(as.ITime(V2) %% 86400, clab, labels=clab[-1], include.lowest = TRUE), V3)]`