# Grouping dates and times

Tags: r, datetime, grouping, lubridate, iso8601

Is there an R package that provides grouping of dates and times for all of the typical time units (seconds, minutes, etc.)?

Or put another way: how would I truncate to multiples a particular time unit?

## Background

I often need to group responses to HTTP requests into 15 second intervals.

Function `lubridate::floor_date()` and `lubridate::ceiling_date()` got me started, but

I came up with something based on the modulo (`%%`), but it feels like I'm reinventing the wheel regarding operating on atomic time components.

## Function definition

```r
library(magrittr)

group_date <- function(
  x,
  interval = 15,
  unit = c(
    "seconds",
    "minutes",
    "hours",
    "days",
    "weeks",
    "months",
    "bimonths",
    "quarters",
    "seasons",
    "halfyears",
    "years"
  )
) {
  # Validate units:
  unit <- match.arg(unit)

  # Possibly base units on "basic units" as {lubridate} does:
  # parsed_unit <- lubridate:::parse_period_unit(unit)
  # n <- parsed_unit$n
  # basic_unit <- lubridate:::standardise_period_names(parsed_unit$unit)

  if (unit %in% c("bimonths", "halfyears", "season")) {
    stop(stringr::str_glue("Unit '{unit}' not supported yet"))
  }
  # No clue how these would need to be handled yet

  # Extract unit value:
  unit_value <- dplyr::case_when(
    unit == "seconds" ~ as.numeric(lubridate::second(x)),
    unit == "minutes" ~ as.numeric(lubridate::minute(x)),
    unit == "hours" ~ as.numeric(lubridate::hour(x)),
    unit == "days" ~ as.numeric(lubridate::day(x)),
    unit == "weeks" ~ as.numeric(lubridate::isoweek(x)),
    unit == "months" ~ as.numeric(lubridate::month(x)),
    unit == "quarters" ~ as.numeric(lubridate::quarter(x)),
    unit == "year" ~ as.numeric(lubridate::year(x))
  )

  offset_factor <- dplyr::case_when(
    unit == "seconds" ~ 1,
    unit == "minutes" ~ 60,
    unit == "hours" ~ 60 * 60,
    unit == "days" ~ 60 * 60 * 24,
    unit == "weeks" ~ NA_real_, # Seconds per week -> no clue how to do that,
    unit == "months" ~ NA_real_, # Seconds per month -> no clue how to do that
    unit == "quarters" ~ NA_real_, # Seconds per quarter -> no clue how to do that
    unit == "year" ~ NA_real_ # Seconds per year -> no clue how to do that
  )

  # Calculate time offset to lower group boundary:
  time_offset <- unit_value %% interval

  # Apply offset:
  x - (time_offset * offset_factor)
}
```

## Grouping seconds

```r
x <- c(
  "2020-01-31 13:01:14",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:15",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:16",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:29",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:30",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:31",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:44",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:45",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:46",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:59",
  "2020-01-31 13:02:00",
  "2020-01-31 13:02:01"
) %>%
  lubridate::ymd_hms()

x %>% group_date()
#>  [1] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:15 UTC"
#>  [3] "2020-01-31 13:01:15 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:15 UTC"
#>  [5] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#>  [7] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:45 UTC"
#>  [9] "2020-01-31 13:01:45 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:45 UTC"
#> [11] "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC"

x %>% group_date(30)
#>  [1] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [3] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [5] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#>  [7] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#>  [9] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#> [11] "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC"

x %>% group_date(45)
#>  [1] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [3] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [5] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [7] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:45 UTC"
#>  [9] "2020-01-31 13:01:45 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:45 UTC"
#> [11] "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC"

x %>% group_date(60)
#>  [1] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [3] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [5] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [7] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [9] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#> [11] "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC"
```

## Grouping minutes

```r
x <- c(
  "2020-01-31 13:04:00",
  "2020-01-31 13:05:00",
  "2020-01-31 13:06:00",
  "2020-01-31 13:29:00",
  "2020-01-31 13:30:00",
  "2020-01-31 13:31:00",
  "2020-01-31 13:44:00",
  "2020-01-31 13:45:00",
  "2020-01-31 13:46:00"
) %>%
  lubridate::ymd_hms()

x %>% group_date(15, "minutes")
#> [1] "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC"
#> [3] "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:15:00 UTC"
#> [5] "2020-01-31 13:30:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:30:00 UTC"
#> [7] "2020-01-31 13:30:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:45:00 UTC"
#> [9] "2020-01-31 13:45:00 UTC"

x %>% group_date(30, "minutes")
#> [1] "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC"
#> [3] "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC"
#> [5] "2020-01-31 13:30:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:30:00 UTC"
#> [7] "2020-01-31 13:30:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:30:00 UTC"
#> [9] "2020-01-31 13:30:00 UTC"

x %>% group_date(45, "minutes")
#> [1] "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC"
#> [3] "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC"
#> [5] "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC"
#> [7] "2020-01-31 13:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:45:00 UTC"
#> [9] "2020-01-31 13:45:00 UTC"
```

---

## EDIT

Just came across `hms::trunc_hms()`.

Seems to give me what I need for `secs = 15` and `secs = 30`, so it would solve my immediate problem. But I can't see how it would work for time units other than seconds:

```r
library(magrittr)

x <- c(
  "2020-01-31 13:01:14",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:15",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:16",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:29",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:30",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:31",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:44",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:45",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:46",
  "2020-01-31 13:01:59",
  "2020-01-31 13:02:00",
  "2020-01-31 13:02:01"
) %>%
  lubridate::ymd_hms()

x %>% hms::trunc_hms(15)
#>  [1] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:15 UTC"
#>  [3] "2020-01-31 13:01:15 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:15 UTC"
#>  [5] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#>  [7] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:45 UTC"
#>  [9] "2020-01-31 13:01:45 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:45 UTC"
#> [11] "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC"

x %>% hms::trunc_hms(30)
#>  [1] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [3] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [5] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#>  [7] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#>  [9] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#> [11] "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC"

x %>% hms::trunc_hms(45)
#>  [1] "2020-01-31 13:00:45 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:00:45 UTC"
#>  [3] "2020-01-31 13:00:45 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:00:45 UTC"
#>  [5] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#>  [7] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#>  [9] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"
#> [11] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 UTC"

x %>% hms::trunc_hms(60)
#>  [1] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [3] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [5] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [7] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#>  [9] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 UTC"
#> [11] "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 UTC"
```

## EDIT 2

Looking into the suggestion to use `cut()`

```r
x %>%
  tibble::enframe() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    grp = value %>% group_date(15)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(
    grp_2 = cut(as.POSIXct(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '15 secs')
  )
# # A tibble: 12 x 4
# # Groups:   grp [4]
# name value                   grp_2                   grp                
# <int> <dttm>                  <dttm>                  <fct>              
#   1     1 2020-01-31 13:01:14.000 2020-01-31 13:01:00.000 2020-01-31 13:01:14
# 2     2 2020-01-31 13:01:15.000 2020-01-31 13:01:15.000 2020-01-31 13:01:14
# 3     3 2020-01-31 13:01:16.000 2020-01-31 13:01:15.000 2020-01-31 13:01:14
# 4     4 2020-01-31 13:01:29.000 2020-01-31 13:01:15.000 2020-01-31 13:01:29
# 5     5 2020-01-31 13:01:30.000 2020-01-31 13:01:30.000 2020-01-31 13:01:29
# 6     6 2020-01-31 13:01:31.000 2020-01-31 13:01:30.000 2020-01-31 13:01:29
# 7     7 2020-01-31 13:01:44.000 2020-01-31 13:01:30.000 2020-01-31 13:01:44
# 8     8 2020-01-31 13:01:45.000 2020-01-31 13:01:45.000 2020-01-31 13:01:44
# 9     9 2020-01-31 13:01:46.000 2020-01-31 13:01:45.000 2020-01-31 13:01:44
# 10    10 2020-01-31 13:01:59.000 2020-01-31 13:01:45.000 2020-01-31 13:01:59
# 11    11 2020-01-31 13:02:00.000 2020-01-31 13:02:00.000 2020-01-31 13:01:59
# 12    12 2020-01-31 13:02:01.000 2020-01-31 13:02:00.000 2020-01-31 13:01:59
```

Created on 2020-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (v0.3.0)

Comment: You can just use `cut()`. Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451761/how-to-group-time-by-every-n-minutes-in-r)?

Comment: @Sotos Doesn't seem to work for me. When I run `x %>% cut(breaks = "15 min")` I get a vector of factors back with `Levels: 2020-01-31 13:01:00`

Comment: Not like that...try `enframe(x) %>% group_by(grp = cut(as.POSIXct(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '15 secs'))`

Comment: @Sotos Well... sorry for not making that obvious connection after being pointed to `cut()`. Still doesn't give me what I want, though (see edit #2)

Comment: Oh you want it to always start at time H:00:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this simple function to round to any given number of seconds, minutes, hours, days, or weeks? In case you want to start your chunks at a specific date and time, there is an optional default origin time. The arguments to "units" are matched so you can abbreviate. It defaults to seconds

```r
time_group <- function(times, intervals, since = as.POSIXct("2000-01-01"), 
                       units = c("secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks"))
{
  all_units <- c("secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks")
  units     <- match.arg(units, all_units)
  intervals <- intervals * c(1, 60, 3600, 86400, 604800)[match(units, all_units)]
  cuts      <- intervals * floor(as.numeric(difftime(times, since, units = "secs"))/intervals)

  return(as.POSIXct(cuts, origin = since))
}
```

This allows you to do this:

```r
# Units default to seconds so this groups by 15 seconds at a time
time_group(x, 15)
#>  [1] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:15 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:15 GMT"
#>  [4] "2020-01-31 13:01:15 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:30 GMT"
#>  [7] "2020-01-31 13:01:30 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:45 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:45 GMT"
#> [10] "2020-01-31 13:01:45 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 GMT"

# We have used argument matching so we can abbreviate minutes to "m"
time_group(x, 1, units = "m")
#>  [1] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT"
#>  [4] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT"
#>  [7] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT"
#> [10] "2020-01-31 13:01:00 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 GMT" "2020-01-31 13:02:00 GMT"
```

Comment: Yep, I think that's the same basic approach that `hms::trunc_hms()` uses: `trunc(as.numeric(x)/secs) * secs`

Comment: How would I generalize it to other time units when wanting to group/truncate to multiples of that time unit, though?